# How to open a Port on Server

Tags: python, ios, sockets, server, backend

I am new to opening a port and server side programming. And I am trying to open a port on my server in python and then form an iOS app get some data from that port. I have done some research and know I can open a port like this

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()                # Close the connection
```

But my question is lets say I just wanted to retrieve a simple string from this port how do I add that string to this open port, I have found some ways to get data from the port in iOS like this library https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort but how do I put the data like a string on the open port?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the method `s.accept()` it will return the socket object as the first return. You can call `socket.rescv` method to read data -

```
data = c.recv(1024)
```

But do remember this is a blocking call. For more information, you can read this [post](http://www.binarytides.com/receive-full-data-with-the-recv-socket-function-in-python/).

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean, could you add a bit more? And would you know how to get that string in iOS, if not that fine, but im still a bit confused?

Comment: Basically - you open a port and attach a socket for it from python. iOS can connect to this port via TCP. When you send something from the server-side using `c.send()`. You can read the socket from iOS - `serialPort:didReceiveData:` callback -https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort#receiving-data

Comment: okay what is the varaible c? Im trying to figure it out from the sample you posted in the answer but  I cant see it?

Comment: variable c is the socket connection returned when you call accept() method

Comment: the github, ORSSerialPort librairy is only for OSX apps do you know of one for iOS apps?